# user_login and password_login correct, but are not working PDOPHP

Tags: php, authentication, pdo

I am trying to get my login script to work using PDO. The problem I am having is that when a user types in his/her username and passsword, it goes to the section of the code where it says it is incorrect, even if the password is correct. What can I do to fix this, and where can I implement the PDO error to show up to possibly help diagnose the problem.

The Login Script from index.php

```
<?
//Login Script
if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
    $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password_login=md5($password_login);
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=socialnetwork', 'root', 'abc123');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ':user_login' AND password = ':password_login' LIMIT 1";
    $db->prepare($sql);
    if ($db->execute(array(
    ':user_login' => $user_login,
    ':password_login' => $password_login))); {
        if ($sql->rowCount() > 0){
            while($row = $sql->fetch($sql)){
                $id = $row["id"];
            }
            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
            $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
            $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
            exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
        } else {
            echo 'Either the password or username you have entered is incorrect. Please check them and try again!';
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<? include("inc/incfiles/header.inc.php"); ?>
<?
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
//declaring variables to prevent errors
$fn = ""; //First Name
$ln = ""; //Last Name
$un = ""; //Username
$em = ""; //Email
$em2 = ""; //Email 2
$pswd = ""; //Password
$pswd2 = ""; //Password 2
$d = ""; //Sign up Date
$u_check = ""; //Check if username exists
//registration form
$fn = @$_POST['fname'];
$ln = @$_POST['lname'];
$un = @$_POST['username'];
$em = @$_POST['email'];
$em2 = @$_POST['email2'];
$pswd = @$_POST['password'];
$pswd2 = @$_POST['password2'];
$d = date("y-m-d"); // Year - Month - Day

if ($reg) {
    if ($em==$em2) {
        // Check if user already exists
        $statement = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username');
            if ($statement->execute(array(':username' => $un))) {
                if ($statement->rowCount() > 0){
                    //user exists
                    echo "Username already exists, please choose another user name.";
                    exit();
                }
            }
                    //check all of the fields have been filled in
                        if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {
                            //check that passwords match
                                if ($pswd==$pswd2) {
                                    //check the maximum length of username/first name/last name does not exceed 25 characters
                                        if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
                                            echo "The maximum limit for username/first name/last name is 25 characters!";
                                        }
                                        else
                                            {
                                                //check the length of the password is between 5 and 30 characters long
                                                    if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
                                                        echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                        {
                                                            //encrypt password and password 2 using md5 before sending to database
                                                                $pswd = md5($pswd);

                                                                $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);

                                                                $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
                                                                $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (username, first_name, last_name, email, password, sign_up_date)';
                                                                $sql .= 'VALUES (:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :sign_up_date)';

                                                                $query=$db->prepare($sql);

                                                                $query->bindParam(':username', $un, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                                                $query->bindParam(':first_name', $fn, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                                                $query->bindParam(':last_name', $ln, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                                                $query->bindParam(':email', $em, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                                                $query->bindParam(':password', $pswd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                                                $query->bindParam(':sign_up_date', $d, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                                                                $query->execute();

                                                                $query=$db->prepare($sql);

                                                                $array = array(
                                                                ':username' => $un,
                                                                ':first_name' => $fn,
                                                                ':last_name' => $ln,
                                                                ':email' => $em,
                                                                ':password' => $pswd,
                                                                ':sign_up_date' => $d);
                                                                $query->execute($array);

                                                                die("<h2>Welcome to Rebel Connect</h2>Login to your account to get started.");
                                                        }
                                            }
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo "Your passwords do not match!";
                                }
                        }
                else
                    {
                        echo "Please fill in all fields!";
                    }
            }
    else {
        echo "Your e-mails don't match!";
    }
}
?>
<?
//Login Script
if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
    $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password_login=md5($password_login);
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=socialnetwork', 'root', 'abc123');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ':user_login' AND password = ':password_login' LIMIT 1";
    $db->prepare($sql);
    if ($db->execute(array(
    ':user_login' => $user_login,
    ':password_login' => $password_login))); {
        if ($sql->rowCount() > 0){
            while($row = $sql->fetch($sql)){
                $id = $row["id"];
            }
            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
            $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
            $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
            exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
        } else {
            echo 'Either the password or username you have entered is incorrect. Please check them and try again!';
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
<table class="homepageTable">
        <tr>
            <td width="60%" valign="top">
             <h2>Already a member? Login below.</h2>
             <form action="index.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="user_login" id="user_login" placeholder="username" />
                <br />
                <input type="password" size="25" name="password_login" id="password_login" placeholder="password" />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Login to your account!">
             </form>
            </td>
            <td width="40%" valign="top">
             <h2>Sign up below...</h2>
            <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="text" size="25" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<? echo $fn; ?>">
            <input type="text" size="25" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<? echo $ln; ?>">
            <input type="text" size="25" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<? echo $un; ?>">
            <input type="text" size="25" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<? echo $em; ?>">
            <input type="text" size="25" name="email2" placeholder="Re-enter Email" value="<? echo $em2; ?>">
            <input type="password" size="25" name="password" placeholder="password" value="<? echo $pswd; ?>">
            <input type="password" size="25" name="password2" placeholder="Re-enter Password" value="<? echo $pswd2; ?>"><br />
            <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!">
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

home.php

```
<?
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
//If the user is not logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}
else
{
//If the user is logged in
echo "Hi, $user, You're logged in<br />Welcome to what is soon to be your NEWSFEED 
<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout?</a>
";
}
?>
```

header.inc.php

```
<?
include ("inc/scripts/db_connect.inc.php");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {

}
else
{
header("location: home.php");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Rebel Reach - PHS Student Social Network</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="headerMenu">
      <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                  <img src="img/find_friends_logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="search_box">
                  <form method="get" action="search.php" id="search">
                  <input name="q" type="text" size="60" placeholder="Search..." />
                  </form>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                  <a href="#">Home</a>
                  <a href="#">About</a>
                  <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                  <a href="#">Login</a>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: are you saving your password in the DB as a md5 encrypted version of the password? try to comment out the $password_login=md5($password_login); and try to see if you can login that way ...

Comment: @henser Yes, I am encrypting the password before it gets to the database, but if it is being encrypted before it goes in and is the same password before it passes through, it should work. trying right now

Comment: If you would like a cleaner PDO lib you might want to use my tiny [DByte lib](https://github.com/Xeoncross/DByte) which insures prepared statements for all your queries.

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer** but some advice for your code that couldn't fit in the comment. You can greatly reduce your code; actually you shouldn't repeat functionality too often... You can reduce:

```
$fn = ""; //First Name
$ln = ""; //Last Name
...
$fn = @$_POST['fname'];
$ln = @$_POST['lname'];
...
```

To half by writting it like this:

```
$fn = (!empty($_POST['fname'])) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
$ln = (!empty($_POST['lname'])) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
$un = (!empty($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$em = (!empty($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$em2 = (!empty($_POST['email2'])) ? $_POST['email2'] : '';
$pswd = (!empty($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$pswd2 = (!empty($_POST['password2'])) ? $_POST['password2'] : '';
```

Furthermore, although this would require some other changes, you can reduce that to a couple of lines by writing it in an array like this:

```
// Retrieve user data
foreach (array('fname', 'lname', 'username', 'email', 'email2', 'password', 'password2') as $Value)
  $User[$Value] = (!empty($_POST[$Value])) ? $_POST[$Value] : '';
```

Comment: thanks for the tips Frank. Always nice to have shorter/compact and clearner versions of code. It's like writing a 20 page essay that could be written in 1 page :D

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why it was duplicating results in the users table. I found the problem though, it was with the section dealing with insert and and the $array

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
"SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ':user_login' AND password = ':password_login' LIMIT 1";
```

When you use PDO prepare method like ? or : do not use single quotation mark (').

correct it like this:

```
"SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :user_login AND password = :password_login LIMIT 1";
```

I hope now it will work!

Comment: I forgot about that! I'm currently in the process of switching it over from mysql to PDO and in mysql its `username='$user_login'`, etc. Testing now.

Comment: Resalat Haque I did that, but now I am receiving `Fatal error: call to undefined method PDO::execute() in ... line 110` The line is the one with the code `':user_login' => $user_login,` with execute being on line 109 `if ($db->execute(array(`

Comment: Going to try to define $db as a solution

Answer (score 0):

RE your "Fatal error: call to undefined method PDO::execute() in ... line 110" issue:

"execute()" is a method in PDOStatement, not PDO, which is why your "$db->execute..." blew up.

(I know this should be a comment, but I'm not allowed yet. Sorry)